# How to design relation between a class Bill and a class SimplifiedBill?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, entity-relationship, class-design

So as the title mentions, I have `SimplifiedBill`, which has only *date* and *finalPayment*, and I also have `Bill`, which has same properties as `SimplifiedBill`, but also all the other details (*taxes*, *user data*, *services*, etc.).

A solution could be for `Bill` to inherit from `SimplifiedBill`, but I don't think that's conceptually correct, because `SimplifiedBill` is something that you get out of `Bill`, so `Bill` is not something "below" `SimplifiedBill`, it doesn't inherit anything from it.

Any ideas on how to implement a class design here?

EDIT:
The process is the following.
I have a `SimplifiedBill` list that I get from the back, and when I click on one of them, I request and get from the api that `Bill` and go into a detailed view.

In case you're wondering, I'm using Angular, and I have a `ListComponent` (or view) where I have my `SimpleBill` objects, and when I click on one of those I go to `DetailComponent`, where I can see that specific `Bill`. When I go from one view to another I cannot transfer the object `SimpleBill`, but only its id (or some other field).

Comment: @juzraai that is also what I thought, but a date and a finalPayment are not really a Bill, and I think that would be misleading to anyone reading the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I agree, inheriting from SimplifiedBill would be conceptually incorrect. 
In general, I think it as advisable to use inheritance sparingly. I rarely see it used correctly.

Instead, I would recommend a compositional approach: If Bill includes SimplifiedBill, then I think it would make sense to have a data structure Bill that has properties for the details:

```
let bill = {
  details: {...},
  simplifiedBill: {...}
}
```

Note here I used a simple object (which - as you are using javascript - might also be worth consideration), but it is equally applicable to a class based approach as well.
You might want to think of a different name for the simplified bill though. Maybe something like "summary".

But in general, it is good that you thought of the concept of inheritance that might not quite fit here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Typescript, so it has to be a class based aproach. I also thought about this solution, but the problem is that in a first request to the API, I get a lot of these `SimplifiedBill` objects, and when I access one of them I would get all the details of that specific `SimplifiedBill`. So we go back to the first problem, because even if I use composition, I would have to build these two different objects/entities, which I don't know how to relate yet.

Comment: Even in typescript, you do not **have** to use classes ;). What exactly do you mean "when I access the simplified bill"? You mean you have some kind of detail view for a bill right? Even in that case, the approach I described is more than fine. In fact, I can imagine a lot of summaries in a list request that load their detail data on click. Depending on your views (it's really hard to say), you should also consider not relating these objects at all. Of course they are somehow related. But they do not have to be related in code.

Comment: Yes, I have a `SimplifiedBill` list, and when I click on one of them, I get into the detailed view that you mentioned of a `Bill`. In case I use your solution, I would have to dynamically create a bill (at the beginning, I won't have any details). I don't mean it's something bad, just thinking out loud. I also agree with what you said about not having to relate them at all. I'm trying to decide between these two solutions.

Comment: I'll think about what option to choose from what you said, but I think they are the correct ones. I edited your answer to include the 'not-relate' option :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to think that you probably don't even *need* a relationship here; it sounds like the `SimplifiedBill` class is more of a simple projection of the `Bill` class.

One way of approaching this would be to keep the two classes totally separate, and introduce a third class, something like a `SimplifiedBillFactory`, which takes a `Bill` and produces a `SimplifiedBill`.

e.g.(pseudo code, probably not valid typescript!)

```
export class SimplifiedBillFactory
{

  createSimplifiedBill(bill: Bill) : SimplifiedBill
  {
     return new SimplifiedBill{
             billId=bill.Id,
             date=bill.date,
             finalPayment=bill.calculateFinalPayment()
     };         
   }
}
```

One advantage of this approach is that if you need to augment `SimplifiedBill` to include more details (like maybe some aggregates like the total count of line items, etc) it's easy to do it here in this class. In addition it encourages you to keep the actual behaviours of a bill within the `Bill` class itself and expose them via methods (e.g. such as `calculateFinalPayment` method on `Bill`)

You could also just use a factory method on the `Bill` class instead of a separate factory class, but personally I would prefer to keep this separate, for example, if you need to use some other class later on in addition to the `Bill` class, to create your `SimplifiedBill` instance.

Comment: This is a nice one, but i cannot use it in my case because the `SimplifiedBill` comes directly from the back, before even having any `Bill`

Comment: @JaviMarzán ah ok, I see. But in that case I'm not sure what the premise for the question is, I mean, it seems in this case they simply don't need to be related at all, are you trying to achieve something specific related to `Bill` and `SimplifiedBill`? If `SimplifiedBill` is just used as a back-end lookup (via `billId` or whatever), then I'd say you don't need to worry about relating the two things at all :)

Comment: Yeah I agree, @LucasManzke also just said it, I think that it may be best not to relate them. Thanks! I will accept accept his answer as he said it before, but thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

interesting question,

**Inheritance is a kind of `is-a` relation**. Ask yourself if A is a B when you create inheritance relation between them.

- **1st question: What makes a simplest Bill or what should a Bill have at least?** the answer also answers what a `Bill` should be.

Since `SimpleBill` is also a kind of `Bill`, so the subset of `SimpleBill` makes `Bill`, Bill itself can be as simple as only have a billId (according to the comments) . so `Bill` would be:

```js
interface Bill{
    billId: string;
}
```

- **2nd question: is `VerboseBill` a `SimpleBill` or the reverse?**, the answer also answers if there is a inheritance relation between them.

It's strange to say `SimpleBill` is a `VerboseBill` or the reverse, so they don't have inheritance relation;

In the future, you may have other bills, like `AaaBill{taxes}`, `BbbBill{services}`..., do they have inheritance relation? but  they are all `Bill`!

My proposal:

```js
export interface SimpleBill extends Bill{
  date: number;
  finalPayment: number;

}

export interface VerboseBill extends Bill{
    date: number;
    finalPayment: number;
    taxes:number;
    services;...
    userData;...
}

export namespace Bill{

    export function simplify(bill:Bill): SimpleBill{
        return {id: bill.id, date: bill.date, finalPayment: bill.finalPayment};
    }

    export function verbose(bill:Bill): VerboseBill{
        if((bill as VerboseBill).taxes !==undefined){
            return bill as VerboseBill;
        }
        return fetchVerboseBill(bill.id);
    }
}

export namespace SimpleBill{
    export const verbose = Bill.verbose
}

export namespace VerboseBill{
    export const simplify = Bill.simplify
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really interesting, I liked it. However, there are limitations that don't allow this solution. I'm using Angular, and when I click on a `SimplifiedBill`, I go to other view/component. The thing is, when i do this I can only pass something as a billid to the new `component` as a reference, so I cannot do `SimpleBill.verbose(bill)` in the new view. It is best if with the id that I passed as a reference I simply get the `VerboseBill`. So I think the best solution here would be not to related them at all, as the other two contributors stated (I'll accept @LucasManzke's answer)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for answering, I found your approach quite interesting

Comment: then it means, Bill itself can be as simple as only contains a `billId`, like 
`interface Bill{ id:string}`, and then you can use the `Bill.verbose(bill:Bill)` method to get the `VerboseBill`.

Comment: @JaviMarzán you'd better updates your question by including the details you mentioned in comments.

Comment: No, because in the `ListComponent` (or view) I have some objects, and in `DetailComponent` I'll have another one. I cannot transfer the `SimpleBill` from one view to another. The only thing that I'll have in `DetailComponent` when I go in there is the `billId`, so it makes no sense to use that to get the `SimpleBill`, and then with that bill get the `VerboseBill`. It's more straightforward to simply get the `VerboseBill` with the `BillId` that i got. Also, I don't really agree with the entity `Bill` that you mention with only an id, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: And `SimpleBill` is not really a Bill, is just the sum up or some data from the Bill, but is not really a kind of `Bill`.